# Postgres ODBC 32 bit driver fails to read volume of 10K records via SSIS

Tags: postgresql, ssis, odbc

We use SSIS(32 bit) to extract data from Postgresql (9.*, 64 bit).
The ODBC (32 bit) was downloaded from postgres (tried both 9.* and latest versions as 10.*) and configured DSN supports well to extract only small volume of data.

When I have the count of say around 105000 records, the connection is not succeeding and driver fails to read the data from Postgresql.

Any advise or recommendation pls.

Comment: For-Loop container and reading in chunks (up to 9K) records.

Comment: "Not succeeding" in what way? please post an error or a more detailed explanation.

Comment: One correction in this. It was issue with 100K records data read and not 10 thousands. Error message from driver when it tries to read is: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. Socket Error Code:10060

Comment: That sounds like the source database is overloaded and cannot return the records in time. Since it  it "did not properly respond after a period of time", your first stop is to extend the timeout

Comment: It is resolved now. I have requested the SQL admin to extend the time out plus modified the command timeout to 0 in SSIS ADO source. This helped.

Comment: *Postgres 9.\**  covers [**6** major versions](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). You need to be a bit more precise on which "Postgres 9"  version are you referring to.

Answer (score 0):

It is resolved now. I have requested the PostgreSQL admin to extend the time out plus modified the command timeout to 0 in SSIS ADO source. This helped.